# Scroll Issue scroll not working

Tags: html, css, scroll

The idea is to have the banner and nav bar stuck to the top of the browser window which i don't want to scroll and the content underneath being able to scroll. The two sections of contentleft and contentright I want to have the same height even if the content isn't as big.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #034569;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #235B79;
}
.contentwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  position: fixed;
  top: 175px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#contentleft {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #034569;
  float: left;
}
#contentright {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your css you need the banner and nav bar to have the `position:fixed` property, which will prevent scrolling. If `.contentwrapper` has a static height declared we can make the div elements inside fill the height with `height:100%;`. Also we can assign html and body a height: `html, body: height:100%;`.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height:100%;
}
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #034569;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 125px;
  background-color: #235B79;
}
.contentwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  padding-top: 175px;
  height:300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#contentleft {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #034569;
  float: left;
}
#contentright {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
}
```